# Searching by related fields in django admin

Tags: python, django, relational-database

I've been looking at [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields) for `search_fields` in django admin in the attempt to allow searching of related fields.

So, here are some of my models.

```
# models.py
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class AgeGroup(models.Model):
    group = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Runner(models.Model):
    """
    Model for the runner holding a course record.
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    agegroup = models.ForeignKey(AgeGroup)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, blank=True, null=True)


class Result(models.Model):
    """
    Model for the results of records.
    """
    runner = models.ForeignKey(Runner)
    year = models.IntegerField(_("Year"))
    time = models.CharField(_("Time"), max_length=8)


class YearRecord(models.Model):
    """
    Model for storing the course records of a year.
    """
    result = models.ForeignKey(Result)
    year = models.IntegerField()
```

What I'd like is for the `YearRecord` admin to be able to search for the team which a runner belongs to. However as soon as I attempt to add the `Runner` FK relationship to the search fields I get an error on searches; `TypeError: Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains`

So, here is the admin setup where I'd like to be able to search through the relationships. I'm sure this matches the docs, but am I misunderstanding something here? Can this be resolved & the `result__runner` be extended to the team field of the `Runner` model?

```
# admin.py
class YearRecordAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = YearRecord
    list_display = ('result', 'get_agegroup', 'get_team', 'year')
    search_fields = ['result__runner', 'year']

    def get_team(self, obj):
        return obj.result.runner.team
    get_team.short_description = _("Team")

    def get_agegroup(self, obj):
        return obj.result.runner.agegroup
    get_agegroup.short_description = _("Age group")
```

Comment: You should try `'result__runner__team__name'`. Remember: you are passing a field to build a `icontains` lookup, so it can't be a `ForeignKey`. If it works, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @Germano - You got it! I wasn't sure if there might be a default method to resolve a FK. Is there something you can add to return a field by default of a FK similar to that of a __str__() method on a model?

Comment: Afaik there is no such a thing as a default model text search field. I'll post the answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The documentation reads:

*These fields should be some kind of text field, such as `CharField` or `TextField`.*

so you should use `'result__runner__team__name'`.

Comment: Thanks, same problem in `django-extensions` autocomplete