# Django 3.0 admin searching for different models fields

Tags: python-3.x, django, filtering

I faced with some problems with project which I had now...
I have different models with included structure (one category can have multiple subcategories)
and I want to implement searching by each field which I had in model...
now it looks like this code working only for 1st level categories:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import *


    def register_models(models_list):
        for model, fields in models_list.items():
            model_fields = ()
            for field in model._meta.fields:
                if field.name in fields:
                    model_fields = (field.name, *model_fields)
    
            class Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
                list_display = ('__str__', *model_fields)
                list_filter = model_fields
                search_fields = [*model_fields]
    
            admin.site.register(model, Admin)
```

Question, is it possible somehow to implement searching for my structure with many subcategories?
I.E if I am in category2 with many subcategories I want to search in category2 subcategory which contains any field with text `test`

Comment: I wouldn't dynamically generate your admins it likely complicates matters. I assume you aren't doing any dynamic generation of models, so just create regular admins. If you include your admins someone might be able to offer some more advice. You can also see how to search on related fields here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569687/searching-by-related-fields-in-django-admin

Comment: @markwalker_ thank you!!! now all is working... I'm new in Django and didn't thought that  each model can be separated for admin =)